# How can I install a windows iso from ubuntu without a flash drive

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8.1, windows-installation

So my windows 8.1 broke today with the error of winload.exe going corrupt. I'm at a loss. I don't know where to start. I had to do this once already a few months ago when I infected myself with a RAT on accident and ended up ruining my windows. I don't even remember what I did. I have grub with 2 non working copies of ubuntu. They work but the video settings are ruined and it will only go into hard terminal mode after the ubuntu splash. I'm on my laptop now trying to bang out a Bootable usb with ubuntu on it so I can get an iso for my copy of 8.1.
Long story short I need to know how to install a copy of windows via iso from ubuntu without any outside storage devices. Because I have no working sticks over 4gb

Comment: Point blank, you don't.  You can either burn a optical disk or use a 4GB flash stick, but you need an installation disk.

Comment: I've done it before. Just not without a completely broken windows. I booted into the broken windows via safe mode and mounted the iso and installed it from there. Which has worked until now. There is a way to mount and install an iso from inside ubuntu. I just have no idea how it works

Comment: Hell, it's even possible to mount and install an iso through grub

Comment: Neither of which I have any clue how to do. But I know it s possible

Comment: You could use a virtual CD/DVD reader ==> http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/12/install-virtual-cd-drive-cdemu-ubuntu-1404/

Comment: Would it work with an executable based disc like windows? This may be exactly what I need